# Phone field on Accounts form

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm-2013, microsoft-dynamics, accounts

I've a very basic question to clarify the difference of depiction of **Phone field** at the form of accounts and in the view/advanced find/data import matched fields.

Actually, the label of the field is set to **Phone** but its display name is **Main Phone**.

Answer (score 1):

An attribute's Display Name is the name that will show up in Advanced Find and Views. You can override this Display Name in the Form by double-clicking on the attribute to bring up the Properties window.

As you've seen, it can be confusing for users if the attribute is called one thing on the form and another thing in views and Advanced Find. I recommend keeping them the same unless there is a good reason not to.